# Consider the complex numbers z1=-8√2-(8√2)i and z2=2√3+2i

Tags: complex-numbers

a) show clearly that 2cis(13π/16) is a fourth root of z1.

I was able to answer this by showing that 2cis(13π/16) to the fourth power is equal to z1.

b) find the other fourth roots of z1 and plot in a complex plane

I know that z1=16cis(π/4) but I am unsure as to what co-terminal angles to add to the answer to question a.

c) z2^3

Would this just be 64cis(π/2) using DeMoivre's theorem?
If so, what would z1/z2 be?

Comment: The others three roots form with the fourth a square with the "midpoint" at the $(0,0)$. You can calculate them with $z^n=r\cdot cis(a) \Rightarrow z={r}^{1/n}\cdot cis(\frac{a+2k\pi}{n})$, where $k=0,..,n-1$.

Comment: could you give me an example using numbers..? does it matter that I have to find the fourth roots (not like a third root)?

Comment: Let's take that $z_1$ of yours. $z_1^{1/4}=2cis(\frac{\pi/4 + 2k\pi}{4})$. Now you have $(z_1)_0=2cis(\frac{\pi}{16}), (z_1)_1=2cis(\frac{9\pi}{16}),...$ and then you have 2 more to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a)

Due to DeMoivre's theorem, $\sqrt[4]{a\text{cis}(\theta)}=\sqrt[4]a\text{cis}\left(\frac\theta4\right)$

b)

I know that $z_1=16\text{cis}(\pi/4)\dots$

Actually, $z_1=16\text{cis}(-\pi/4)\text{ or }z_1=16\text{cis}(7\pi/4)$

$16\text{cis}(\pi/4) = 8\sqrt 2 + (8\sqrt 2) i$

But what are the other roots.

$z_1=16\text{cis}(-\pi/4 + 2n\pi)$ the roots are, $2\text{cis}(-\pi/16 + n\pi/2)$, where $n=0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3\dots$

c) Yes, that is correct.